# extend repeater by adding button to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im trying to extend repeater control in asp.net. I want to for example add button which changes color ofr text in control from black to red (thats just an example).

I created web User Control and changed the inheritance from

```
public partial class MyRepeater : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

to:

```
public partial class MyRepeater : Repeater
```

ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyRepeater.ascx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater" %>
```

then in ascx I wanted to add the button but there is an error on compilation:

```
ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
```

How can I easilly extend repeater with one button (I need to extend cause in real example this button will do something else so other solutions which chages color wouldt help me).

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Spotted the error was not what I first thought...

You are changing a UserControl to a server control extension hence the

```
extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl <---- Note by extending Repeater you now no longer extend UserControl)
```

What you need to do is create a ServerControl (create a class on it's own without the ascx.cs bit and you should be fine and dandy. You will need to get your head around server control development particularly DataBoundControl, also read up on the Render methods etc. I suggest just a good general read on server control authoring from MSDN

Comment: Changed to reflect mistake @gruber and added what you need to look at _ could probably knock up a quick server control for you that extends repeater but I think you'll gain more by going through the articles in MSDN